# Outlook 2016 - Bounce Back error " Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients"

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-client

I know this a common question from everywhere, But I already try all the solutions nothing have worked.

First Error persist only when..

I forward an email from specific sender with an pdf attachment. But if without pdf attachment It will sent without an issue.

And here's the test I tried.

1.) I forward an email thru web mail. It worked. ( so the problem is on the outlook.)

2.) Since Outlook have a problem I try to forward an email outside the domain . eg. google.com, yahoo.com and so on... It's fine.. But when I try to forward an email within my domain I have bounce back error

"Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipient"

Not on all emails with pdf attachement but on a specific email address only.

Example if I forward all emails from billing@domain.com with .pdf attachment will bounce back..

Anyone can help me on this matter?

Thanks

Comment: Usually, there is more data in the NDR that describes the reason why the message was not delivered. Take a look at the headers and server response.

Comment: So it only happens when forwarding a specific message? How big is the PDF attachment? Are you in cached Exchange mode? If so, you may try switching to online Exchange mode to see whether the issue is replicable.

Comment: @SteveFan

Not specific message but specific contact with an attachment. the pdf is usually not more than 1mb. Yes I tried but still I have those error

Comment: Never met such an issue.. Can you save the PDF file first and then try sending a new email with the PDF file attached? What if we save the PDF attachment to your desktop first, then click Forward, remove the original PDF attachment and attach the PDF file you just saved on your desktop?